# C# documentation about how to add an event handler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ffmpeg, nreco

I am coding a video converter using NRECO and ffmpeg everything works but when it comes at to get the Progress time 
i've tried

```
pgbConversion.Value = FFMpegConverter.ConvertProgress();
```

but it is impossible so i got ! 
**
**ConvertProgress is an even; please check C# documentation about how to add an even handler.****

from NReco 
please how can i get the video progress knowing that ConvertProgrss is an event

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't mean "event" and not even? In which case I would see what property I need to assign an expression to, probably using a lambda. I'm unfamiliar with this framework, but if you wanted to add a function to a button click event is would be something like button.onClick += (s,e) => DoSomething();

Comment: What is pgbConversion? Is that a progress bar?

Answer (score 2):

You write this:

```
FFMpegConverter.ConvertProgress +=
```

**Your** Visual Studio starts helping you out by offering to attach event handler code to the ConvertProgress event for you. It will show you a pop up, like **MY** visual studio is doing here, in this screenshot of me attaching an event handler to a Timer.Elapsed event, which is a totally different event, on a different object, that I'm using as an example to demonstrate how visual studio helps you attach events to things:

[image]

Then **you** press TAB in **YOUR** visual studio to accept the suggestion in the pop up

Visual Studio will scaffold a basic event handler for you, and you can add your code into it that you want to be run every time the event is raised. Here is what **my** visual studio did when I pressed tab during adding an event handler to my example using Timer:

[image]

(Naturally my pics show VS making a handler for Timer.Elapsed, not FFMpegConverter.ConvertProgress, because I have Timer, but I don't have that FFMpegConverter class.. "**Pics are for illustration purposes only** - you are NOT supposed to type the code you see in my pictures")

Comment: hello thanks for the answer, but i get an error on this line

Comment: FFMpegConverter.ConvertProgress += new System.Timers.Timer().Elapsed += Program_Elapsed;

Comment: Did you read the last line of my post?

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property  'FFMpegConverter.ConvertProgress' Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to ....

Comment: Sorry i haven't read it i would try it thx

Comment: you need to make an instance of the ffmpegconverter class, like `var ffmpgcnv = new FFMpegConverter();` then you need to follow the advice in this post, but on the `ffmpgcnv` variable instead, I.e. `ffmpgcnv.ConvertProgress+={press Tab key}`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's not a typo and they mean "Event"? In which case I would assign  lambda expression to the event, or you could just reference another method as seen below, so the documentation would be here: [Lambda Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions), [Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/).

Example w/o Lambda:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ffMpeg = new FFMpegConverter();
    ffMpeg.ConvertProgress += FfMpeg_ConvertProgress;
    ffMpeg.ConvertMedia("input.mov", "output.mp4", Format.mp4);
}

private static void FfMpeg_ConvertProgress(object sender, ConvertProgressEventArgs e)
{
    // Percent complete as a double
    pgbConversion.Value = e.Processed.TotalSeconds / e.TotalDuration.TotalSeconds;
}
```

Example w/ Lambda expression:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ffMpeg = new FFMpegConverter();
    ffMpeg.ConvertProgress += (s, e) => {
        pgbConversion.Value = e.Processed.TotalSeconds / e.TotalDuration.TotalSeconds;
    };
    ffMpeg.ConvertMedia("input.mov", "output.mp4", Format.mp4);
}
```

The event only has the total number of seconds in the video and the number of seconds that's been processed. They are also represented as TimeSpan objects. I'd advise getting the total number of seconds of each of these (returning a double), and then dividing to get a percentage complete. Of course you could use either of them as [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) instances individually.

Comment: thanks, please i have an eror here : pgbConversion.Value =  it shows that it is non-static

Comment: Could you add the code? Is the class that pgbConversion instantiates a standard part of the .NET library?

Comment: How come you switched away from using the lambda version? I thought that was quite neat..

Comment: Wasn't directly relevant to the question. I wanted to prioritize what was specifically being asked over the technical level of the answer. Since you've asked, however, I can add it :)